# Problems with using session data using nw.js with PHP web server

Tags: php, session, nw.js

I am trying to convert my web game into a desktop app. Everything works except for the session data. I got websockets, images, audio, and all of that working. Great! But when I try to authenticate, it POSTs to the web server just fine, returns a successful authentication, and attempts to reload the page. However, upon page reload, the subsequent AJAX requests cannot get any of the $_SESSION values again.

I was able to find my PHPSESSID using win.cookies.getAll inside of the nw.js app, but I don't see how this helps me at all. Normally this is automatic when loading the webpage from the server. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the php file you are postig to? 
First thing that comes in my mind: are you using `session_start()` at the top of your php script?

Comment: Yeah, this is something that works fine if I load it from a normal web browser.

Comment: Okay, it might seem like a minor comment, but you helped me out. First of all I got some sleep and now I'm thinking more clearly. All of my problems boiled down to using the wrong absolute path to point to the file I was using to authenticate. It actually works now... I'm super tired, but also incredibly happy. Now, I will rest.